# Assign topics to workers with no duplication

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I'm working on a site which uses the Twitter API, specifically to track individual keywords. I need to distribute this load across multiple workers, however to maximise the number of requests I can make I need to make sure that the following happen each time the assignment function is run (approximately hourly):

- Each worker is assigned as close to equal share as possible
- Workers which were previously assigned a keyword keep that keyword where possible
- No keyword is assigned to multiple workers

I have two objects which define the keywords, and workers. See an example below. For error testing sake, as you can see I've got multiple workers tracking the same campaign, which should never happen, but it needs to be able to reassign again even if it does.

```
// Topics
[{
  topics: ['marathon', 'education', 'computing', 'schools'],
  campaign: 'Some random campaign 1'
},
{
  topics: ['education', 'sport', 'tourism', 'london'],
  campaign: 'Some random campaign 2'
},
{
  topics: ['ict', 'sport', 'fintech'],
  campaign: 'Some random campaign 3'
}]

// Workers
{
  "9779959f-2e99-4083-b578-eb9f31c60b46":{
    "worker":"9779959f-2e99-4083-b578-eb9f31c60b46",
    "topics":["marathon","digitaljersey","fintech", "sport", "education", "ict"]
  },
  "129a5e00-0d77-4156-98df-e1795ac2bccc":{
    "worker":"129a5e00-0d77-4156-98df-e1795ac2bccc",
    "topics":["education","sport","marathon"]
  },
  "3240f648-522a-4eb3-befb-b03f0181f329":{
    "worker":"3240f648-522a-4eb3-befb-b03f0181f329",
    "topics":["ict","computing","utilities"]
  }
}
```

As you can see, the topics are an array of objects, each which has the keywords to be tracked. These can have an arbitrary number, and may repeat keywords across campaigns.

I have my workers object, which details the topics they are currently assigned. These both are provided to my function.

The approach I took was to create a topic map by iterating over the topics. Then I iterated over the workers, checking if its topic is present in the topic map. If it isn't, then it doesn't need to be tracked. If it is, I then set the `worker` value in the topic map to the `worker` value of the assignment. In following iterations, it checks for the presence of this, and if it is there then it is already accounted for, and ignored.

I then iterate over the topics map, and find any without an assignment, and add them to a reassignment array. Then, I count the number in both the reassignment array, and in total, and determine the number per worker. Any which are 30% or more over this get one taken at random and pushed to the reassignment array until they are within the 30% boundary.

I then assign one to each worker, and continue till the array is empty. However, it is not working at all. I end up with duplicates, unassigned topics and more.

Here is the output for the above:

```
9779959f-2e99-4083-b578-eb9f31c60b46
  -> fintech
  -> sport
  -> education
  -> ict

129a5e00-0d77-4156-98df-e1795ac2bccc
  -> sport
  -> computing
  -> marathon

3240f648-522a-4eb3-befb-b03f0181f329
  -> computing
  -> london
  -> fintech
```

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/6q29m9y9/

Could anyone either help me sort this out, or suggest a better way of doing it?